# Ввод клавиатуры с тайм-аутом в Python. Как сделать чтобы программа не ждала вечно?

Tags: python-3.x, input, timeout

Программа запускается, и должна по умолчанию ждать 100 секунд ответа пользователя, но ждёт вечно, пока не будет ввода. Как сделать чтобы программа ждала только 100 секунд?

Например, в программе ниже, если пользователь ввел `1`, то программа выполняет сейчас функцию, иначе пользователь ничего не ввел, будет ждать 10 часов и после этого выполнит функцию для работы. Как для консоли написать программу, что работало примерно так:

```
work():
    print('это работает сейчас')



import time
print ('выполняем программу через 10 часов или сразу? 1 - сразу, *- через 10 часов(ничего не введено)')
s = input('')

if s ==1:
    work()
else:
    time.sleep('36000')
    work()
```

Comment: Примечания: функция `input()` возвращает **строку**, затем Вы эту строку сравниваете с числом. Надо либо приводить строку к числу, либо сравнивать строку со строкой. Почему Вы в `time.sleep()` передаёте строку? Необходимо передавать число (можно даже с плавающей точкой). Функции объявляются с префиксом `def`. `def work():`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409034/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я создал для этого класс-обёртку, используя `threading`:

```py
from threading import Thread


class Inp:
    inp = None

    def __init__(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.get_input)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join(timeout=100)

    def get_input(self):
        self.inp = input()

    def get(self):
        return self.inp


inp = Inp().get()
print(f'Вы ввели {inp}' if inp else f'Вы ничего не ввели!')
```

Но данный код несовершенен, ввод получается "одноразовым". Мы можем продолжить программу, но если пользователь так ничего и не ввёл, то консоль всё ещё продолжит ждать его ввода. В Вашем случае - это не проблема, но решение неуниверсально.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input/15533404#15533404

```py
from threading import Timer

def work():
    print('это работает сейчас')


timeout = 36000
t = Timer(timeout, work) # Заводим таймер с обратным отсчетом 10 часов, который по тайм ауту выполнит функцию work
t.start() # Запускаем таймер

print ('Выполняем программу через 10 часов или сразу? 1 - сразу, *- через 10 часов (ничего не введено)')
s = input()

if s == "1": # Если пользователь ввёл "1", то отменяем отсчёт таймера и запускаем функцию сразу
    t.cancel()
    work()
```

Стоит учитывать, что если 10 часов пройдёт, функция сработает, а потом пользователь введёт "1", то функция сработает ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

В питоне есть библиотека для этих целей `timeout_decorator`

С её использованием, ваша задача решается так

```
import time
from timeout_decorator import timeout, TimeoutError

# decorator for setting timeout on function execution
# seconds - how musch seconds to wait
# default - value that will be returned on timeout
def set_timeout(seconds, default=None):
    def _decorator(function):
        function = timeout(seconds)(function)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except TimeoutError:
                return default
        return _wrapper
    return _decorator


# waits for function execution
# function - function with timeout
# seconds - how musch seconds to wait
# default - value that will be returned on timeout
def wait_for(function, seconds, default=None):
    return set_timeout(seconds, default)(function)


def work():
    print('это работает сейчас')

wait_input = wait_for(input, 100)

text = wait_input()

if text == '1':
    work()
elif text is None:
    print('timeout')
    time.sleep(36000)
    work()
```

В итоге таймаут можно выставить для любых существующих функций с помощью `wait_for` (создав новую функцию, но с таймаутом)

```
wait_input = wait_for(input, 100)
```

Либо для своей функции с помощью декоратора `set_timeout`

```
@set_timeout(100)
def wait_input():
    # some more code
    return input()
```

А также есть возможность задать возвращаемое значение по умолчанию, которое вернётся, если пользователь ничего не ввёл

```
wait_input = wait_for(input, 100, default='sleep')
text = wait_input()
if text == '1':
    work()
elif text == 'sleep':
    time.sleep(36000)
    work()
```

Answer (score 1):

@nomnoms12, я дополнила код и вот что получилось:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def work():
    print('работает')

class Inp:
    inp = None

    def __init__(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.get_input)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join(timeout=5)

    def get_input(self):
        self.inp = input()

    def get(self):
        return self.inp


print('Введите что-нибудь и выполниться сейчас, иначе выполниться через 1 час...')
inp = Inp().get()
if inp:
    print(f'Вы ввели {inp}')
    work()
else:
    print(f'Вы ничего не ввели! Выполниться через 1 ЧАС')
    time.sleep(3600)
    work()
```